# Cognos error -Data items cannot be moved to a data container that uses a different query

Tags: cognos

I have two lists on my report page. In report studio, I am trying to drag one list on top of the other with the intent of creating a master detail relationship between the two lists.

I am getting this error:`Data items cannot be moved to  a data container that uses a different query.` But when we link two data items through a master detail relationship, the data items will always refer to different queries. No?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always do this by putting all of the detail/header data into one list, then pick a header column and click 'section'. Then unlock the list and drag the remaining data items into the header